# App crashes when receiving a VoIP call before unlocking after reboot

Tags: crash, voip, linphone, ios16, pushkit

My app is using Linphone and PushKit to handle VoIP calls. It works well when the app is in the foreground, background, or suspended (killing app).

If we restart the phone and the app receives a VoIP call before the phone is unlocked (i.e. PIN is entered for the first time) then the app crashes - this is shown to the user when they unlock the phone.  The crash only occurs in iOS 16 (and not with iOS 14).

Reboot -> make a VoIP call to the phone -> unlock -> crash. (iOS 16)

We've tested with other VoIP apps (e.g. Skype, Messenger); they do not crash but they do not notify the user that a call is received. There is just a notice that a call was missed when the phone is unlocked. We would like the same behaviour (i.e. do not crash, show a missed call).

What do we need to do to properly handle this use case?

Crash report:

[image]

Comment: Please attach at least the stacktrace of the crash and the logs before it, otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: Thanks @Viish.
I added an image about the crash report that we got.
I think it is not useful much tbh.
It crashes when rebooting... so there is no log in the app itself.

Comment: Indeed your screen doesn't help. However if there is a crash there is at least a stack trace and a few logs from our SDK before it. If there isn't then the issue doesn't lie in Linphone-SDK.